# Disappearing DIV or DIV border

Tags: html, css

I'm working on an orbit simulation I have the planet orbiting. When You zoom all the way in (click the + sign) and select Neptune (the last planet on the right - might have to scroll the top planet bar) its orbit (the dashed line) disappears. If you zoom out 1 then its orbit is visible, some times. Zoom out again or any farther and its always visible. Any way to prevent it from disappearing?

You can see a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jzaun/Pe87m/).

If it matters, I'm on the latest Chrome for mac. I downloaded and tried this on the latest Firefox for the mac, and the issue is not there. I tried it in the latest Safari as well and its not there, so this must be a Chrome specific issue, not a webkit issue.

This may be a bug in Chrome. I filed a [report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=129534).

Comment: Will take some time to dig out  the problem. Just to let you know that the bug can be also reproduced on latest Chrome for Windows.

Comment: Have you considered SVG instead of HTML for your retained-mode graphics API?

Comment: @Phrogz - Thanks for the comments, I didn't know the term `retained-mode graphics`, learned something new. I will look into SVG.I don't think the issue is related to the javascript, but rather how much of a DIV is displayed compared to whats offscreen. My thought is it's being culled as not important, or (if this were 3d) out of my field of view, like when an object gets to close to the camera position, just the 2d equivalent of that. I was hoping someone may have run into this before and knew a work around, thats why I didn't post the code directly in my question and just described the issue.

Comment: @Justin808 I suspect your guess about the cause is correct. The issue is not so much that the code wasn't here, but rather that you do not seem to have made an attempt to pare down your code to the smallest possible test case, isolating the problem, first. My suggestion about SVG does not remove JavaScript, but may change what bounding box logic is used.

Comment: I'm on the latest Chrome for Mac and I can not reproduce the problem. Could this be a quirk stemming from a slow CPU or low amount of available RAM? I have lots and lots of both so it's a little difficult to test on my end I'm afraid.

Comment: @PatrikAlienus - Can you look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/jzaun/Ux5QK/  How many lines do you see? 3 (dotted, dashed and solid)? I only see 2 (dashed and solid). I'm also on the latest Chrome and and latest MBA so ram and speed shouldn't be an issue either.

Comment: @Justin808 Nope, I only see 2 - a solid and a dashed. However when I change some values for the dotted one, it appears: http://jsfiddle.net/PTZ39/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give the div a background colour, you'll see that it's the border that disappears.

As a workaround, the border stays visible if you change the border width to 3px (at least on my Chrome 19 (Linux)). Perhaps you can set the thicker width for the highest zoom levels.